# Code-igniter Can its possible to login with the same user ? and also making a refresh page every people who have same username?

Tags: codeigniter

**Can Codeigniter allow multiple users login with the same username ?** and also making a refresh page every people who have same username ? for example, having 3 people login with the same username in different places. Person A uploaded file then redirect to the same page and not had an upload button. The button will disappear after Person A used. **The question is How can I made Person B and C not see an upload button after Person A used it.** Redirect with sending session id then refresh ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's quite a system. If you're implementing the login and using Codeigniter sessions, then: Yes, you can allow multiple users to login. Codeigniter sessions are based on browser/ip/etc - not on username. So, you control the logic of the app and you can determine in your libraries and controllers if you allow multiple logins with the same username.

The other part of your question is also based on the logic of your app. You'll have to keep track of the CI sessions and add the usernames or other identifying information to the session  with:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username', 'userA');
```

Then, when `userA` clicks that upload button, you'll have to save that as well:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('upload_clicked', 'userA');
```

Then, for your other users, you'll have to query the `ci_session` database to see if userA has clicked that upload button to determine if you should show the button to the other users:

```
$results = $this->db->query("SELECT user_data FROM ci_sessions WHERE user_data LIKE '%upload_clicked%'");

// pseudo-code below:
// this will give you all the records with `upload_clicked` saved in user_data
// then loop through those results and unserialize user_data
// then check if upload_clicked == userA
```